# How to catch TimeoutException in BeginInvoke()

Tags: c#, asynchronous, begininvoke

My hope is that test.BeginInvoke() throws an TimeoutException after the time limit.
but, It doesn't catch TimeoutException.
How can I fix it? Thank you so much.

```
public delegate void AasyncDelegateCaller(int callDuration, out int threadId);

public void AasyncDelegate(int callDuration, out int threadId)
{
    Thread.Sleep(callDuration);
    threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    Console.WriteLine("TimeoutException");
    throw new TimeoutException();
}


private static void Search()
{
    try
    {
        int threadId;
        Program p = new Program();
        AasyncDelegateCaller caller = new AasyncDelegateCaller(p.AasyncDelegate);
        IAsyncResult result = caller.BeginInvoke(3000, out threadId, null, null);
        SearchProgram(); // Sometimes it takes a long time. So I want to throw TimeoutException at that time
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It takes Long! Bye");
    }

}
```

Comment: Using a delegate's BeginInvoke() method is a mistake and not portable.  Use Task instead.

Comment: I tried using Task, but It couldn't catch TimeoutException too.
`public static void work()
{
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Console.WriteLine("TimeoutException");
    throw new TimeoutException();
}
///main part///
Task task = new Task(work);
try
{

    task.Start();
    SearchProgram();
}
catch (TimeoutException)
{
}`